# Chrome cast not rendering m3u8 file from Amazon S3 server(Android)

Tags: android, chromecast

Currently i am using google default receiver app for streaming in chrome cast device. my all media files hosted amazon s3 server. So when i am trying to stream m3u8 file from amazon s3 server its not working, chrome cast not printing any log also. From my investigation i got to know because my CORS header issue. By default i am not able retrive CORS header from amazon S3 server ,for getting CORS header i have to add ORIGIN header in request as per amazon S3 configuration . So currently i am using proxy server for communication, through proxy server i am able to retrieve CORS header , but still chrome cast not streaming specified URL.

Working Url : http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8

Not Working : https://d2jq3q8q84i66g.cloudfront.net/production-df0ec56d-0fbb-bc2c-11e7-354ff3af9c4e/14f06349888835ba1dcac47e20d0e8ebeaa90773799c33ed37243d56715c5eec/t/5769893f8701b703003ab829/index.m3u8

Comment: You need to turn on logging and take a look at the receiver logs.

Comment: How can i enable logs in chrome cast  receiver app.?

Comment: (1) Register a styled receiver (it is identical to the Default Receiver but allows you add some styling and allows you to debug the receiver), (2) Follow the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging

Comment: Without registration is there any way for finding logs.?